# SG1 - Gemini - Why was not Sam Carter at fault for losing the only weapon that could stop a Replicator?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

She screwed up by letting the Replicator of herself have access to the design of the weapon.  Usually this type of screw up is done by Daniel Jackson.  But after this happens everyone is telling her that she shouldn't feel bad as it wasn't her fault. Why?

Answer (score 5):

A few relevant quotes from the episode:

"T'ealc, what have I done?"
"You cannot be held responsible for the actions of the replicator."

"This isn't your fault."

"Carter, she isn't you."
"O'Neil is correct, though she shared your memories, her personality was altered."

They're not trying to tell her that she didn't screw up by allowing the replicator access to the weapon.  It's fairly obvious that she should feel lousy for letting an enemy get the drop on her like that.

They're trying to be tactful in saying that she shouldn't feel worse because it was a replicator version of herself.  Carter is still empathizing with the replicator version, and may feel that because the replicator betrayed the SGC she is personally participated in that betrayal, beyond what she'd feel if it had been some other random bad guy who betrayed them in the exact same way.

Comment: OK, Bob, I'll except that she isn't responsible for the action of the replicator. But her commander should also be holding her accountable for letting down her gaurd in dealing with her replicator.  He should have said 'your screwed up.  Don't do it again, now get back to work."

Comment: Is it really her screw up though?  She's military.  She kept her superiors (in this case, O'Neil) informed about the actions she was taking.  She never disobeyed orders and she didn't try to conceal what she was doing.  Ultimately, he carries that responsibility.  If O'Neil felt that giving the replicator access to the ARW was too big of a risk, he could have put an end to it at anytime.

Comment: I agree, if there was some kind of inquiry O'Neill would take the blame as the commanding officer, and Hammond would back O'Neill for making a difficult choice. Neither would blame Carter for what happened.